# AWS S3 Presigned URL to PUT object with additional user params not working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to generate a presigned url to put files into s3 with some additional metadata with it

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucket, objectKey)
        .withMethod(httpMethod)
        .withExpiration(expiration);
if (params != null) {
  params.forEach(
      (k, v) ->
          generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter(
              Headers.S3_USER_METADATA_PREFIX + k.toLowerCase(), v));
}
```

where params is a `Map<String, String>`

but after uploading file when I try to get the object using

```
AmazonS3.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key).getUserMetadata()
```

returns an empty map.

Also tried `generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader(key, value)`
But I see that in the generated url string the header values are not being sent.

Note : I am sending `Amazons3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString();` to UI

Any help will be appreciated.
Additional Note : I am trying to do this in my local mockS3 server which is not HTTPS

Comment: If I manually add headers with S3_USER_METADATA_PREFIX from UI, it gets reflected in while getting back the object. But I want to add this data when I generate this url, not when I use it to put file

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing request parameters and request headers.

`addRequestParameter` adds *request parameters* to the signed URL.

While S3's PUT operation expects *request headers* to add meta data (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html)

You need to use `putCustomRequestHeader` instead.

Note that in addition to signing with these parameters, the client that
actually sends the request will have to pass the same values as actual
headers. In other words both the URL generator code and client code need to
know the headers being sent.

Comment: as per my requirement client code dose not know the headers beings sent.
or in other words they just need to PUT a file to the url which generator gives.
Any way to do this ?

Comment: well, if the client has no knowledge of the headers, I can only think about proxying the request from the client and let the proxy do the heavy lifting : upload to S3 and using the correct headers.  A request Header is passed by the client as part of the HTTP protocol.  An URL (even a signed URL) can not "contains" HTTP headers.