# Generate signed URL for Google Cloud Storage with additional our own parameter

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to generate a signed URL for Google Cloud Storage with additional parameters made by us (such as X-Goog-OurParameter=Hello)?. In AWS S3 it is possible to do that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462488/aws-s3-presigned-url-to-put-object-with-additional-user-params-not-working))

Answer (score 1):

All of the URL signing parameters are [documented](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).  There are no custom parameters.